# Create table from a CSV file

Tags: java, parsing, csv, io, bufferedreader

I am using the following code for inserting data from a file to a Swing based `JTable`.

```
String line;
data = new Vector();
columns = new Vector();
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\abc00");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine(), "\t");
    while (st1.hasMoreTokens())
            columns.addElement(st1.nextToken());
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(line, "\t");
            while (st2.hasMoreTokens())
                    data.addElement(st2.nextToken());
    }
    br.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It's forming the table correctly but everytime omitting the first row of the file i.e. if the file has 5 rows then the table contains 4 rows. Is it due to this line?

```
StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine(), "\t");
```

Then how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you already read the line (as below) and your cursor moved to next line and hence you missed first line.

```
StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine(), "\t");//think of what if you dont have any line?
```

You could read it in a string variable when you have line in your file and then use it or you could redefine buffered reader.

Comment: I added like **StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer("a b", "\t");** It works now. Thanks.